# Tell me whether this Unknown Operation Exists.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I need to know whether the below unknown operation, denoted by $\boxplus$ exists.

If $v_1=a \boxplus X$ and $v_2=b \boxplus X$, where $X$ is an identical value in both $v_1$ and $v_2$:

equation (1):   $ c_1 \cdot v_1+ c_2 \cdot v_2=c_1\cdot a+c_2\cdot b$

TBN: All values are integers and $v_1 \neq a,v_2\neq b$

Comment: How about defining $Y\boxplus X = Y$? Then $v_1 = a\boxplus X = a$, and $v_2 = b\boxplus X = b$, and your equation (1)is true.

Comment: @HowDoIMath thanks for the hint. I've modified the question.

Comment: Should this work for _any_ integers $X,a,b,c_1$ and $c_2$? Should $v_1\neq a$ hold for _all_ $X$?

Comment: @Arthur Ideally yes. Since I have no idea even for special case, I would consider any cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the expression
$$
c_1(a\boxplus X) +c_2(b\boxplus X) = c_1a+c_2b
$$
As a function of $a$. This is a linear function. That means that $c_1(a\boxplus X) = c_1a +c_2b - c_2(b\boxplus X)$ is linear with respect to $a$ as well. This value should not depend on $b$, which means that
$$
c_2b-c_2(b\boxplus X) =c_2(b-b\boxplus X)
$$
is the same number no matter what $b$ is, so the *slope* of the linear function $b\mapsto b\boxplus X$ must be $1$.

Lastly, we have that
$$
0\boxplus X +0\boxplus X=0+0=0
$$
so the constant term is $0$. Therefore, the only operation $\boxplus$ that fulfills your conditions is the operation $$a\boxplus X=a$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you know the $v_1,v_2,a,b$ before you know the $c_1,c_2$ [which seems to be the case]: Equation (1), all by itself, is either very easy or very difficult to satisfy, depending on the quantifiers:

- The fact that $c_1v_1+c_2v_2 = c_1a+c_2b$ for all $c_1$ and $c_2$ means that 
  $$c_1(v_1-a)=c_2(v_2-b)$$
  In particular, this must hold for $c_2=0$ and $c_1\neq 0$, which means $v_1=a$. Similarly, $c_1=0$ and $c_2\neq 0$ gives $v_2=b$. Even if you do not permit zero, the same result can be achieved by screwing around with the prime factorizations on both sides.
- If you only need to find the existence of $c_1$ and $c_2$ which satisfy Equation (1), these are easy to find: it would be good enough to let $c_1=v_2-b$ and $c_2=v_1-a$.

Answer (score 1):

For all strictly positive integers $c_1,c_2$, we have

$$c_1 \cdot v_1+ c_2 \cdot v_2=c_1\cdot a+c_2\cdot b$$

$c_1+1$ is also a strictly positive integer, so we have

$$(c_1 + 1) \cdot v_1+ c_2 \cdot v_2=(c_1 + 1)\cdot a+c_2\cdot b$$

Subtracting the first equation from the second:

$$v_1 = a$$